# ResourceBundle in Google App Engine Servlet does not work as expected

Tags: java, google-app-engine, internationalization, resourcebundle

Can someone help me to understand why internationalization using `ResourceBundle` does not work in Google App Engine Servlet the same way it works in a command line Java application?

The following snippet:

`ResourceBundle resource_en_US, resource_de_DE, resource_ja_JP;`

`resource_en_US = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleBasename, Locale.US);`
`resource_de_DE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleBasename, new Locale("de_DE"));`
`resource_ja_JP = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleBasename, new Locale("ja_JP"));`

`logger.info("resource_en_US:" + resource_en_US.getLocale());`
`logger.info("resource_de_DE:" + resource_de_DE.getLocale());`
`logger.info("resource_ja_JP:" + resource_ja_JP.getLocale());`

Logs only `en_US` in GAE.

`resource_en_US:en_US`

`resource_de_DE:en_US`

`resource_ja_JP:en_US`

But logs the appropriate Locales in command line Java program.

`resource_en_US:en_US`

`resource_de_DE:de_DE`

`resource_ja_JP:ja_JP`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your properties files are being copied into WEB-INF/classes. You can check this out using a command shell.

Comment: Hi @nacho-coloma, I use Eclipse as development environment and these files are being copied to <project-root>/war/WEB-INF/classes.