# Using a ResourceBundle.Control on Google-app-Engine for localization of a Java application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf-2, internationalization, resourcebundle

I am trying to take a JSF targetted localization application example, and move it from JBoss to Google App engine - and stumbling...

The internationalization example is taken from the final link in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4278571/723554. The [article itself](http://jdevelopment.nl/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/) being based on using a ResourceBundle.Control.
This works fine when deployed to JBoss. However I'd like to see if it can be moved to GAE - and when I setup the Eclipse Project to use GAE, I get the error:

```
    java.util.ResourceBundle.Control is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment
```

The only other [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736571/resourcebundle-in-google-app-engine-servlet-does-not-work-as-expected) here on SO is a few years old - and seemingly unanswered.

So - the question:
Is there a better approach for internationalization on GAE than using a ResourceBundle.Control?

FYI: The intended technologies for the app will be JSF-2, PrimeFaces and PrimeFaces Mobile.

---

[1] App Engine 1.8.1
[2] JSF 2.0

Comment: I met the same problem too.In my case, It's spring mvc (3.2.3).It solved by stop using utf8 property files back to iso-8859-1 and native2ascii. Only for your reference.

Comment: Thanks Clxy for the comment. I'll have to try and use that. (Good to know that I was not alone!)